# How to write Navier stokes equation in 2D along a stream line path?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

How to write navior stokes equation in terms of instantaneous tangent t and normal n at a point on a streamline. ?.

Comment: Your written text does not seem to relate to your original question.  Do you really think you need to write del in terms of tangent and normal to a streamline to implement what the title asks for?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What you want is not coming out clearly.